# How to remove the delay for passing params to a render function when using an action button?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, delay, action-button

The following code produces a GUI where an user can input files paths. The code pre-processes those file paths and safes the results. The idea is that those inputs are passed to a render function for Rmarkdown and, on the first action button press, sends those values to the render function such that another Rmarkdown file is rendered that uses those values.
That is how it works in theory, in practice the first button press causes a render to happen, but non of the params are actually sent along with the first button press. However, the second button press on, everything works fine. Can anyone see the flaw in my code, that is preventing the first button press to behave the way I want it to?

I have tried looking around to see if someone else has figured this out and honestly all I think i figured out is maybe I use isolate()? sorry i am very new to R shiny.

**`GUIforRmarkdowngeneration`**

---

title: "Generate Rmarkdown Report for data"
runtime: shiny

### output: html_notebook

```
#setwd("/home/alan/Desktop/wts/filestosaveandcarryover/tiamatfiles")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE)
library(reticulate) # <- only needed to run python
#use_python("/Users/dyarmosh/anaconda3/bin/python")
```

```
library(shinyFiles)
library(glue)
library(stringr)

ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
  shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Choose forward fastq" ,
                   title = "Please select a file:", multiple = FALSE,
                   buttonType = "default"),
  br(),
  selectInput("Selected_Panel", "Select Panel", choices = c("bacillus","burkholderia","yersinia")),
  br(),
  # #submitButton("Begin Analysis") - fix this no select item from file system
  actionButton("Start", "Begin Analysis")
  ),
  mainPanel(
      br(),
      textOutput("fwdftext"),
      br(),
      textOutput("revftext"),
      br(),br(),
      textOutput("paneltext"),
      br(),br(),
      textOutput("completion")

    ))
)

rvs <- reactiveValues() #renamed to rvs
server <- function(input,output,session){

  volumes = getVolumes()
  observe({  
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)

    req(input$Btn_GetFile)
    req(input$Selected_Panel)
    req(input$Start)

    fwd_selected <- parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)

    rvs$fwdfastq <- as.character(fwd_selected$datapath)
    if (str_detect(rvs$fwdfastq,"R1")){rvs$revfastq <- str_replace(rvs$fwdfastq,"R1","R2")}
    if (str_detect(rvs$fwdfastq,"R2")){rvs$revfastq <- str_replace(rvs$fwdfastq,"R2","R1")}
    class_selected <- parseFilePaths(volumes, input$ClassifierFile)
    kmer_selected <- parseFilePaths(volumes, input$StoredKmerFile)
    rvs$panopt <- as.character(input$Selected_Panel)
    rvs$start <- input$Start
    output$fwdftext <- renderText({paste("Entered Forward File:", rvs$fwdfastq)})
    output$revftext <- renderText({paste("Matched Reverse File:", rvs$revfastq)})
    output$paneltext <- renderText({paste("Entered Panel:", rvs$panopt)})
  })
  observeEvent(input$Start, {
        print(paste(rvs$panopt,rvs$fwdfastq,rvs$revfastq, rvs$class,rvs$kmer))
            rmarkdown::render("testinput.Rmd", 
                      params = list(
                        panelname =  rvs$panopt, 
                        r1filename = rvs$fwdfastq, 
                        r2filename =  rvs$revfastq, 
                        classifier = rvs$class, 
                        kmer = rvs$kmer
                        ), 
                      output_file = paste0("AmpSeqClass_Report_",strsplit(basename(toString(rvs$fwdfastq)),"[.]")[[1]][1],"_",str_replace(c(Sys.time())," ","_"),".html"))

        output$completion <- renderText({paste("Rmarkdown Document render is complete at ",toString(Sys.time()))})
  })

}
observe({
  req(rvs$fwdfastq)
  req(rvs$revfastq)
  req(rvs$panopt)
  req(rvs$start)
})



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**`testinputfile.Rmd`**

---

title: Perform stuff
output:
  html_document:
params:
  r1filename:
    label: "Forward:"
    value: BurkP-130611_S12_100_L001_R1_001.fastq
  r2filename:
    label: "Reverse:"
    value: BurkP-130611_S12_100_L001_R2_001.fastq
  panelname:
    label: "AP:"
    value: bacillus
    input: select
    choices: [bacillus,burkholderia,yersinia]

---

```
setwd("/home/alan/Desktop/wts/filestosaveandcarryover/tiamatfiles")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE)
library(reticulate) # <- only needed to run python
#use_python("/Users/dyarmosh/anaconda3/bin/python")
```

```
print(params)
```

basically if you can get the rmarkdown to generate properly on the first action button click, with non of the passed params being NULL, that is the solution

Comment: Would you be able to simplify this question somewhat? That's a lot of code to "just" test a button-press triggering `render`, I believe you'd be able to generate a trivial example in under 40-50 lines that demonstrates the phenomenon. (Lots of code and be daunting. I won't spend time here trying to parse meaningful code from unrelated, while guessing or faking your data that we don't have.)

Comment: ok I will try to prune it down more

Comment: things I dont know how much of the complexity of my R shiny app might be affecting the results so I have trimmed it down as much as I can while maintaining different types of inputs, etc.

Comment: Do you know how I can modfiy code on the question I asked? when I click edit it is only letting me change my summary and nothing else.

Comment: You should always be able to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57046948/edit) your own questions, that is not a reputation-based privilege/milestone.

Comment: change made. I apologize about the confusion.